# How to auto-generate deploy.cmd in new Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cli

I'm following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-python-configure) to create a web app with a custom `deploy.cmd` file. The article suggests that I can get a copy of the current `deploy.cmd` file (which I'll then modify) using the following command:

`azure site deploymentscript --python`

Unfortunately, when I install the Azure CLI using the MSI linked in the article, there is no `azure` binary on my path. I do have `az` -- is this a newer version of the same CLI? -- but I can't find an equivalent deployment script generation command for that executable.

I found a `deploy.cmd` file using Kudu (under `D:\home\site\deployments\tools`) but am not sure if that's the appropriate file to use. Can anyone suggest the right Azure CLI command for deployment script generation, or confirm that the `deploy.cmd` file I found is the right one to modify? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on my knowledge,  there is not an equivalent to `azure site deploymentscript` in azure cli(2.0). So, you could not do deploy custom script with Azure CLI 2.0.

You had better know the difference between Azure cli 2.0(az) with Azure cli 1.0(azure).

> Azure CLI 2.0: Our next-generation CLI written in Python, for use with
>   the Resource Manager deployment model.
>
> Azure CLI 1.0: Our CLI written in Node.js, for use with both the
>   classic and Resource Managerdeployment models.

For your scenario, if you could install Azure ClI 1.0, you could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cli-install-nodejs) to install Azure CLI 1.0.

Instead of using the command line to generate a starter deployment script, there is an alternative approach that is often easier:

- Deploy your repo without any deployment scripts.
- Go to the site's [Kudu Console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console).
- From the Tools menu, choose 'Download deployment script'. You'll get a zip with a .deployment and deploy.cmd files.
- Commit both files at the root of your repo
- Tweak them as needed

More information please refer to this [link](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console).

Answer (score 5):

You can use **kuduscript** to generate the deployment script.

```
npm install -g kuduscript
kuduscript --python
```

Here is the list of options

```
Options:

    -h, --help                          output usage information
    -V, --version                       output the version number
    -r, --repositoryRoot [dir path]     The root path for the repository (default: .)
    --aspWAP <projectFilePath>          Create a deployment script for .NET web application, specify the project file path
    --aspNetCore <projectFilePath>      Create a deployment script for ASP.NET Core web application, specify the project file path
    --aspWebSite                        Create a deployment script for basic website
    --go                                Create a deployment script for Go website
    --node                              Create a deployment script for node.js website
    --ruby                              Create a deployment script for ruby website
    --php                               Create a deployment script for php website
    --python                            Create a deployment script for python website
    --functionApp [projectFilePath]     Create a deployment script for function App, specify the project file path if using msbuild
    --basic                             Create a deployment script for any other website
    --dotNetConsole <projectFilePath>   Create a deployment script for .NET console application, specify the project file path
    -s, --solutionFile <file path>      The solution file path (sln)
    -p, --sitePath <directory path>     The path to the site being deployed (default: same as repositoryRoot)
    -t, --scriptType <batch|bash|posh>  The script output type (default: batch)
    -o, --outputPath <output path>      The path to output generated script (default: same as repository root)
    -y, --suppressPrompt                Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an existing destination file.
    --no-dot-deployment                 Do not generate the .deployment file.
    --no-solution                       Do not require a solution file path (only for --aspWAP otherwise ignored).
```